# What is the name of this anime with nekomimi?

Tags: identification-request

[image]

I have been wondering for a long time which anime this is from.

Comment: Where do you get this from? The art style suggests that this is from the later half of 200x decade.

Comment: Please provide some more details, like the time range for the anime etc..

Comment: In future, it would behoove you to try using reverse image search on your image - the first 5 results are various booru-style image-sharing websites, all of which list the artist and make it pretty clear that this image (and the characters in it) don't originate from an anime.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is neither about anime nor manga.

Comment: @coleopterist I disagree, the image totally looks like it could have originated from an anime. Just because we now know that the image did not originate from an anime or manga, doesn't mean its off-topic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where is this picture from? How do I use Reverse Image Search to find the source of an anime/manga image?](http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/21618/where-is-this-picture-from-how-do-i-use-reverse-image-search-to-find-the-source)

Answer (score 10):

This isn't from an anime. It's original art by [this Pixiv user](http://www.pixiv.net/member.php?id=970058) (warning, may be a bit NSFW) for her [FC2 blog](http://naomi703703703.blog112.fc2.com/) (also maybe not safe for work).

The characters in the image are:

- Hayami Shizuku (white hair, green eyes)
- Hutaba Akane (blonde hair, red eyes)
- Hutaba Aoi (blonde hair, blue eyes)
- Neko (brown hair)

Answer (score 5):

(All below links are possibly NSFW.)

A larger version of this image can be [found on Danbooru](http://danbooru.donmai.us/posts/1450053?tags=hayami_shizuku). Apparently, this image is just a drawing by [an artist named Naomi](http://naomi703703703.blog112.fc2.com/) as part of her 世界の果ての喫茶店 (Cafe at the End of the World) series.